# MySQL: Importing timestamp from file name

Tags: mysql, xml, timestamp

I was not able to find preliminary asked question to my topic yet.

I have several XML files named "Measurement_2015_06_09_14_53_04.xml". This is a file having the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 -<dataentry>
  -<MesswertArray index="0">
    <PRESSBASE1>3540</PRESSBASE1>
    <PRESSBASE2>87524</PRESSBASE2>
    <PRESSBASEMAIN>32456</PRESSBASEMAIN>
    ...
  -<MesswertArray index="1">
    <PRESSBASE1>246</PRESSBASE1>
    <PRESSBASE2>9852</PRESSBASE2>
    <PRESSBASEMAIN>4568</PRESSBASEMAIN>
 etc.
```

I have a table in MySQL with all the columns from the XML files, including one for the index. I want to add another Timestamp column at the beginning with the timestamp from file namne --> Date 2015_06_09, time 14_53_04.
Is there a way to tell MySQL to use that date in the file as the timestamp and assign it to all the measurements from that xml file?

Thanks a lot in advance for your support!

Answer (score 0):

What if you just add another entries in XML with date of your file?

Comment: Unfortunatly is the operator of the SPS currently not available so that we can not change the settings of the machine creating the XML files for the next two months. That is why we are searching for a workaround.